# Facebook Javascript SDK: /me - is id permanent?

Tags: javascript, facebook

From the api call "/me" I'd like to get a constant with which I'll be able to identify a user.
For instance, name and email can be changed by the user over time, so they're not good way to identify a user for a long period of time.

Is the "id" returned in the callback permanent? Or can different ids be returned for the same user under different circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the id is permanent. Just keep in mind that it´s an "App Scoped ID", so it is only unique and permanent in that one App. Every user will get another ID in another App.

If you want to match the IDs of users between different Apps, you can use the [Business Mapping API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business).

Comment: Basically it's good enough. Is there any other parameter that is constant and the same in all apps?

Comment: no, the id is the only thing to identify a user in a serious way. i will add some more information about different apps.